# How to create custom commands on Linux?

Tags: linux

So I'm here thinking how to create custom commands on my Linux Debian? I mean so I could open up terminal and just type the script name (and possibly some arguments) and it would refer to the script in my home directory. Otherwise I've write the whole path to the script each time and it gets annoying.

Comment: This can be done by setting up Aliases.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I guess it's bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the path of your scripts to `PATH`, just put in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:<script-directory-here>
```

where `<script-directory-here>` is something like `/home/you/scripts/`.

Comment: ... and add "export PATH" on the next line.

Comment: @CarlF: I never understood the usefulness of `export` in `.bashrc`. If you mind a little piece of explanation...

Comment: you could also add a bash alias .. ~/.bash_aliases

Comment: @CarlF You don't need to export it, it's (very likely) already marked as exported.

Comment: Rather, I would _prepend_ my personal path to the `PATH` variable, so as to be able to override otherwise existing commands with my own.

Answer (score 2):

Putting your scripts in their own directory, e.g., ~/bin, as cYrus answered, is probably the best solution. Another way to avoid having to "write the whole path to the script each time", though, is to use shortcuts to refer to certain directories. For example, executing

```
./yourscript
```

will execute a script named *yourscript* in the current directory, and

```
~/yourscript
```

will execute a script in your HOME directory.